# Комбинации заполнения двумерного массива

Tags: комбинаторика

Не найду алгоритм.
Имеется двумерный массив `D` (строк не ограничено, столбцов известно `n`, но может меняться). Имеется массив `M` из `m` элементов.
Как получить все возможные варианты заполнения `D` элементами `M` при условии, что элемент `D[i,j]` может быть заполнен только если заполнен элемент `D[i-1,j]`?

Как пример. Пусть `n=4`, `m=3`, `M = {m1, m2, m3}`?
Тогда мы можем заполнить `D`, например:

```
{m1,   , m2, m3}
{d1, d2, d3, d4} - это просто индексы столбцов D
или
{m3,   ,   ,   }
{m1,   , m2,   }
{d1, d2, d3, d4}
но нельзя делать так (т.к. элемент m3 "оторван" получается)
{  , m3,   ,   }
{m1,   , m2,   }
{d1, d2, d3, d4}
```

Есть ли какой-то алгоритм для получения всех возможных комбинаций заполнения?

Answer (score 2):

Я подозреваю, что проще всего это сделать рекурсивной функцией. Идёте по массиву `D` слева направо, сверху вниз (как будто книжку читаете), и в каждой ячейке `D` либо оставляете пустое место, либо берёте очередное для этого места число из `M`, причем то, которое ещё не было взято ранее (нужен массив флагов, в котором отмечается, какие элементы уже взяты, а какие нет). Поставив очередной элемент (или не поставив ничего), переходите к следующей позиции `D`. При этом, разумеется, проверяете, можно ли поставить элемент по вашему условию (что сверху что-то поставлено, либо это первая строка). Программу писать, конечно, тут вряд ли кто-то будет.

Comment: программу сам напишу, в этом проблем нет. Проблема именно с алгоритмом. В вашей рекомендации - это просто алгоритм случайного заполнения я так понимаю (я случайно определяю заполняю или нет ячейку, причем произвольным элементом M). А мне нужны ВСЕ возможные комбинации заполнения. Как это сделать?

Comment: Я написал именно то, как получить ВСЕ возможные комбинации. Мы не случайно определяем, заполнять ячейку или нет, а в цикле перебираем все возможные символы и ставим и в ячейку по очереди, рекурсивно переходя к следующей.

Comment: можно тогда подетальнее. "либо оставляете пустое место, либо берёте очередное для этого места число из M" - как формализовать это правило "либо"? И по какому алгоритм взять число из M? Ведь там несколько элементов и в каком порядке берем тоже имеет значение?

Comment: Я боюсь, что если Вы не знаете, что такое рекурсия, то Вы не поймёте моё объяснение. Тут всё предельно просто: находясь на некоторой позиции (i,j), перебираем все числа массива `M` (в любом порядке) в цикле. Поставив очередное число в позицию (i,j), переходим к позиции (i,j+1) и делаем там то же самое. Разумеется, нужно проверять, когда можно ставить число, а когда нет. Также нужно проверять, что очередное число, которое мы хотим поставить, не было поставлено ранее куда-то. Если это объяснение непонятно, но я ничем не могу Вам больше помочь, Вам следует сначала изучить рекурсию.

Comment: что такое рекурсия мне вполне знакомо. Я не вижу в вашем алгоритме элемента рандомизации что-ли (которая при этом обеспечит переблр всех комбинаций). В вашем объяснении указано "либо ставим, либо нет". Каким правилом определяется это "либо" для конкретного шага рекурсии?

Comment: @Виктор, если вам только лишь "знакомо" понятие рекурсии, то это не значит, что вы хорошо её понимаете, потому что если бы понимали, то не задали бы этот вопрос. Прочитайте мой комментарий от 28 апреля, там всё написано более подробно. Вы по очереди ставите на очередную позицию все ваши числа, ЛИБО не ставите ничего. При каждом действии шагаете в рекурсию, возвращаетесь и ставите очередное число. Так все варианты будут пройдены. Всё, это было последнее объяснение.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Наверное, не могу корректно уточнить ваше объяснение. Все мои уточнения касаются не самого принципа алгоритма, основанного не рекурсии, а алгоритма определения "ЛИБО", которое обеспечит все возможные комбинации. Как это ЛИБО формализовать? Т.е. в зависимости от нахождения в позиции (i,j) матрицы D и имеющихся незадействованных эл-тов M поставить либо не поставить эл-т M? Вот чего в ваших комментариях не укзаано

Comment: если виртуально на каждом шаге рекурсии добавлять в M пустой элемент, который будет означать, что мы не ставим реальный эл-т в D(i,j), а пропускаем, то получим бесконечную рекурсию, т.к. на определенных итерациях цикла шага рекурсии всегда пропускать будем.